# How can I change the audio output device in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, audio

I'm building a simple Cocoa app and I want to direct the audio output to a specific device, instead of the system selected one. I know some apps, like Skype, let you select where to send the output to. How do they do this?

I tried the MTCoreAudio framework but I can't even compile my app (or their AudioMonitor demo) with it included and the errors aren't helpful (_objc_fatal). Are there any complete examples that I can learn from? So far my searches haven't turned anything up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [CAPlayThrough example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CAPlayThrough/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004443) on the [Mac Dev Center Sample Code library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) shows how to list all of the available input and output devices, and select a default device from a menu.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through the sample code on http://developer.apple.com ?

Look at these projects http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code

Namely the DefaultAudioUnit project.

I should say that working with Core Audio is more challenging than Cocoa.  Most of the API's are C-based (I find that harder).  You should read the Core Audio programming guide as well to get a sense of how the audio system is put together.

Comment: I think you mean the DefaultOutputUnit sample.